# VIM snipmate tab not working

Tags: vim, snipmate

I am not having any luck with Snipmate.  I've used pathogen to install snipmate along with tlib, addon-utils, and snippets.  Here is the output of verbose imap.

```
<S-Tab>       <Plug>snipMateBack
Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
<Plug>snipMateShow * <C-R>=snipMate#ShowAvailableSnips()<CR>
Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/plugin/snipMate.vim
<Plug>snipMateBack * <C-R>=snipMate#BackwardsSnippet()<CR>
Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/plugin/snipMate.vim 
<Plug>snipMateTrigger * <C-R>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet(1)<CR>
Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/plugin/snipMate.vim
<Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger * <C-R>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()<CR>
Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/plugin/snipMate.vim
<S-Insert>    <MiddleMouse>
Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
<Tab>         <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger
Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
<C-R><Tab>    <Plug>snipMateShow
Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
```

Basically, i've created a file called "test.html" and type "html" followed by Tab and the auto completion didn't work.

TIA,

Thomas

Comment: Do you have an `html` snippet?

Comment: Yes. I've installed vim-snippets using pathogen as well.

Comment: Update.  read SnipMate.txt and entered :SnipMateLoadScope! html.  This lets me use the snippets for html.   Did i install the snipmate incorrectly?  Can I load all snippets when i start gvim?  I am running gvim in linux mint 17.3 by the way.

Comment: What is the output of `:echo &filetype` in that `test.html`?

Comment: nothing.  :echo &filetype produces nothing...

Comment: The problem seems to be that Vim does not recognize the file type even if i save the file with .html extension.   if i :set filetype=html, the snippet seems to work.  Why doesn't Vim recognize the extension?

Comment: Because you didn't enable filetype detection. Add `filetype plugin indent on` and `syntax on` to your `vimrc`.

Comment: romainl, you are correct.  actually for some reason i had 'filetype off' at the end of my .vimrc.   Thanks again for all your help!